# hacer delete con modal php

Tags: php, php7

estoy trabajando con bootstrap y php y quiero hacer un delete con un modal pero no se como pasarle el id a ese modal

boton normal para eliminar sin modal:

```
<a href="users/delete_user.php?id=<?php echo $filas['id'] ?>" class="btn btn-danger">
    <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
```

Este es el boton con el que abro el modal

```
<a type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
    <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
</a>
```

Modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Delete</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <b>Are you sure to delete this user?</b>
            <?php echo $filas['id'] ?>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <a href="users/delete_user.php?id=<?php echo $filas['id'] ?>" class="btn btn-danger">
                <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Si es necesario implementar js no importa

Comment: Luis en el boton modal debes pasarle el id del usuario y recibirlo en el modal para que te funcione.

Comment: como seria? explícame porfa

Answer (score 1):

te dejo un ejemplo de como lo hago desde laravel y tu lo organizas:

**Boton para abrir modal de eliminar**

en el `data-target` va el nombre que identificas el modal

```
  <a data-target="#modal-delete-{{$product->id}}" data-toggle="modal" href="" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Eliminar </a>
```

**debe incluir el archivo donde esta el modal, si esta en el mismo archivo del boton obvias el siguiente codigo**

```
@include('admin.producteliminar')
```

despues en el modal eliminar tienes que crear un action con el metodo post y pasarle el id del dato a eliminar, ademas en el id va el nombre del modal que lo identifico en el boton eliminar. `id="modal-delete-`

```
<div class="modal fade modal-slide-in-right" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog" tabindex="-1"
    id="modal-delete-{{$product->id}}">

    <form method="post" action="{!! action('ProductController@destroy',['id' => $product->id]) !!}">
        {{csrf_field()}}
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">

        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header btn-danger">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">x</span>
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Eliminar Producto</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Confirme si desea eliminar el Producto</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer" style="background-color:#E7E7E7">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</button>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>

</div>
```

Comment: ya he tratado poniendo el id en el data target pero no me abre el modal cuando hago eso

Answer (score 1):

para poder realizar el siguiente ejemplo se recolienda utiliza javascript 
dentro de botón tiene que colocar los datos del usuarios con las siguiente código **data-id=""** dentro tiene que colocar los datos

```
<button class="massdelete-modal btn btn-danger"
    data-id="{{ $lists->ida}}"
    data-nombre="{{ $lists->nombrea marcus feliz }}">Eliminar</button>
```

en el codigo javascript

que me tome la informacion de data-id y me lo escriba el campo con el id=id_mass

```
$('#id_mass').val($(this).data('id'));

$('.modal-descripcion').text('Eliminar los datos');
```

```js
$(document).on('click', '.massdelete-modal', function() {
   
   $('#id_mass').val($(this).data('id'));
   $('.modal-descripcion').text('Eliminar los datos');
   $('#msdelete').text('¿Seguro que quieres borrar los datos?'+$(this).data('id'));
   
   $('#massModal').modal('show');
 
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button class="massdelete-modal btn btn-danger"
data-id="{{ $lists->id wwwwwwww}}"
data-nombre="{{ $lists->nombre}}"
>Eliminar</button>

<button class="massdelete-modal btn btn-danger"
data-id="{{ $lists->ida}}"
data-nombre="{{ $lists->nombrea marcus feliz }}"
>Eliminar</button>

<button class="massdelete-modal btn btn-danger"
data-id="{{ $lists->ids aaaaa}}"
data-nombre="{{ $lists->nombres aaaaaa}}"
>Eliminar</button>


<div id="massModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
   <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
     <h4 class="modal-descripcion"></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
     <h3 class="text-center" id="msdelete">¿Seguro que quieres borrar los  datos?</h3>
     <form class="form-horizontal" id="formmass" role="form">
      
      <div class="form-group">
       <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="id">ID:</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id_mass"  disabled>
       </div>
      </div>
      </form>          
      </div>
   </div> 
   </div> 
   </div>
```

Comment: pero eso no es laravel?

Comment: en el ejemplo no estoy utilizando Laravel y lo que usted pide es pasar datos de un botón a un modal, ademas solo se esta utilizando Javascript,JQUERY y HTML que corresponde al frontend de la aplicación y Laravel corresponde al backend,que corresponde al problema que formulaste, una recomendación es utilizar Laravel para su proyecto a futuro y VUEJS por cuestiones de trabajo